# Inserting records into one table coming from two tabs in a Oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

The form i created consists of two tabs, with some cols. When the user enters the data in the tabs and clicks on save, the data must be stored in the table as 2 separate records. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 blocks, based of the same table. So instead of having 1 block spread over 2 tabs, have 2 blocks on 2 tabs. This'll save you creating procedures or start doing some trigger magics (2 blocks are much clearer, than for example having a post-insert trigger with another insert with the same values).
If you have a column which distinguishes between the records, like a type column (A and B, fe), make sure you set a correct where-clause, and don't forget to fill in this value when a new record is created (when-create-record trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Base the block on a stored procedure instead of table and do the magic in the procedure, Check for "stored procedure, creating a data block" in forms builder help for the details.